# flutter reset form key when with Navigator context change

Tags: forms, flutter, dart

New to flutter, so maybe quoting the question in a misleading way. Please correct if so.
I have a flutter form that I want to reset when a button (not the `InkWell`) is pressed. Something like this

```
                Form(
                  key: formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField( ),
                      SizedBox(height: 15),

                      TextFormField( ),
                      SizedBox(height: 15),
                      DateTimePicker( ),

                      SizedBox(height: 15),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                            // navigate to another page, leaving the form as it is, 
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => SharePage(  ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        },
                        child: Container(...)
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                          child : Text('Reset Form'),
                          onpressed : (){
                            //doesn't reset the form when the InkWell above is used to navigate to another page and back
                            formKey.currentState.reset()
                        }
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

It works normally when the `formKey.currentState.reset` is called. But when I press the `InkWell` to go to the `SharePage` and come back from there, the `reset` method of the `formKey.currentState` doesn't resets the form to its initial state, instead it resets the form to the state it was just before going to the `SharePage`. How do I reset the form to the complete initial state even after coming from the `SharePage`?

Answer (score 0):

did you try to update

```
InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SharePage(  ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(...)
                  ),
```

to be like so,

```
InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                        /// add following line
                        formKey.reset
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SharePage(  ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    child: Container(...)
                  ),
```

--UPDATE--

to use resetting functionality from anywhere on the screen

```
 TextButton(
              child : Text('Reset Form'),
              onPressed: () {
                formKey.currentState.reset();
              },)
```

Comment: I've modified the question a little bit, I want to reset the form when a separate button is pressed, not the `InkWell` itself

Comment: @Eular  I've updated the answer too.

Comment: That is exactly my question, I'm using the same thing now, it works when the `InkWell` is not pressed. After pressing the `InkWell` and coming back from the `SharePage` the `reset` doesn't reset the form to the initial state.

Comment: I do it like:

`InkWell(onTap: () {
                        formKey.currentState.reset();
                       
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Emergency(),),);
                      },
                      child: Text('Emergency'),
                    ),`

and that's working with me, please provide ** TextFormField** implementation to reproduce the issue.